# Numeric value insert as 0 in accessdatabase

Tags: ms-access, c#-3.0

I am creating one application where data are inserted into access table using DataGridView. The issue is that two value(s) are inserted correctly but when I'm trying to insert numeric value it's inserted as 0.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            string cmd1 = "insert into Medicine_Available_Detail([Medicine_Name],[Dealer_name],[total_available])values(?,?,?)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            string Medicine_Name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", Medicine_Name);

            string Dealer_name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dealer_name", Dealer_name);

            int Availability;
            bool total_availableHasValue = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total_available"].Value.ToString(), out Availability);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_available", Availability);

            con.Open();
            int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (n > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Help yourself by explaining what columns work and which one doesn't - which one is numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably "Availability" is the numeric value.  Are you sure that the value from the datagridview for total_available is numeric?   If it's not, then Available will be = 0.

You could try testing total_availableHasValue after the parse  or log/debug to check on the contents of the datagridview cell.

Comment: i done below code but still its going into else condition and inserting as 0 int Availability;

                bool total_availablehasvalue = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total_available"].Value.ToString(), out Availability);

                if (total_availablehasvalue)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_available", Availability);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_available", DBNull.Value);
                }

Comment: Ok, but what is the actual value of:

    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total_available"].Value

Can you debug it or output to the console?

Comment: Grayman : i added image, output is coming 0 only and inserted in null

Comment: If I understand correctly, the image shows the contents of dataGridView1.  If that's right, then it looks like all three fields are spaces / empty.   For the Availability column, this means that the conversion via TryParse will fail and the integer Availability variable will be set to 0.
What value do you want to be inserted in the database when the datagrid Availability value is an empty string?